# How do I save a plt figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to save the figure resulting from the code below. I keep getting errors.

```py
x = range(-300,1)
x_2 = range(0,301)
y = range(-300,1)
y_2 = range(0,301)
x_1 = range(-300,1)
y_3 = range(0,-301,-1)
x_3 = range(0,-301,-1)
x_0 = [0 for i in range(301)]
y_0 = [0 for i in range(301)]

plt.plot(x_2,y_2, label="direction 1")
plt.plot(x_2,y_3, label="direction 2")
plt.plot(x_1,y, label="direction 3")
plt.plot(x_3,y_2, label="direction 4")
plt.plot(x_0,y_2, label="direction 5")
plt.plot(x_0,y, label="direction 6")
plt.plot(x_2,y_0, label="direction 7")
plt.plot(x,y_0, label="direction 8")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y");
```

i've tried naming one of the code lines and saving it but it says list has no attribute savefig.
All those lines should be plotted in one figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `plt.savefig("test.png")` at the end of your code and `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` at the beginning, creates a perfectly valid picture on my computer: [image]

Here is the full script:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(-300, 1)
x_2 = range(0, 301)
y = range(-300, 1)
y_2 = range(0, 301)
x_1 = range(-300, 1)
y_3 = range(0, -301, -1)
x_3 = range(0, -301, -1)
x_0 = [0 for i in range(301)]
y_0 = [0 for i in range(301)]

plt.plot(x_2, y_2, label="direction 1")
plt.plot(x_2, y_3, label="direction 2")
plt.plot(x_1, y, label="direction 3")
plt.plot(x_3, y_2, label="direction 4")
plt.plot(x_0, y_2, label="direction 5")
plt.plot(x_0, y, label="direction 6")
plt.plot(x_2, y_0, label="direction 7")
plt.plot(x, y_0, label="direction 8")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.savefig("test.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `plt.savefig()`, or `plt.show()` and then press 's' if you want to see the graph beforehand

Comment: I can only verify what @wychmaster said, I can't reproduce your error